# Reviewing my training program exercises for building muscle

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding

I started training at 87 kg with a 21% Body Fat Percentage I now have 83kg with a 10% Body Fat Percentage I would like to get to 90kg with a 5-6% body fat percentage.Would this program help me?(My dream? big arms rounded shoulders and well defined muscles everywhere on my body)

**Monday Back training**

- Deadlifts 4 x 12 to 15 reps 100kg
- Lat Pull ups 4 x 12 to 15 reps 83kg
- Dumbbell bent over row 4 x 12 to 15 reps 22kg
- Hyperextensions 4 x 12 to 15
- Lat pulldowns 4 x 12 to 15 52kg
- Seated Cable Rows 4 x 12 to 15 52kg
- Back Pullovers as many as I can close to 100 (finalizer) 20kg

**Tuesday Chest training**

- Dumbbell chest press 4 x 12 to 15 20kg
- Dumbbell flyes 4 x 12 to 15 14kg
- Reverse Grip Bench Press 4 x 12 to 15 50kg
- Close Grip Bench Press 4 x 12 to 15 50kg
- Chest Pullovers with dumbell 4 x 12 to 15 22kg
- Cable crossover as many as I can close to 100 (finalizer) 22kg

**Wednesday leg day**

- Barbell Squats 4 x 12 to 15 60kg
- Leg press 4 x 12 to 15 50kg
- Dumbbell Lunges 4 x 12 to 15 20kg each dumbell
- Lying Leg Curls 4 x 12 to 15 45kg
- Leg Extensions 4 x 12 to 15 40kg
- Standing Calf Raises 4 x 12 to 15 82kg
- Seated Calf Raise 4 x 12 to 15 60kg

**Thursday biceps/triceps training**

- Mercy 30 4 sets 20kg
- Barbell Curl 4 x 12 to 15 and after lowering the weight and again 12 to 15 reps 25kg first and after lowering 20kg
- Dumbbell curl 4 x 12 to 15 and after each set doing 12 reps of hammer curl 10kg for dumbbell curl and 6kg for hammer curls
- Overhead Triceps Extension 4 x 12 to 15 reps 24kg
- Cable Triceps Pushdown 4 x 12 to 15 reps 30kg
- Dips triceps 4 sets of reps till failure

**Friday Shoulder training**

- Dumbbell Shoulder Press 4 x 12 to 15 18kg each dumbbell
- Military Press 4 x 12 to 15 30kg
- Lateral Raises 4 x 12 to 15 8kg
- Front Raises 4 x 12 to 15 8kg
- Rear Raises 4 x 12 to 15 8kg
- Dumbbell shrug 4 x 12 to 15 40kg each dumbbell
- Upright Barbell Row 4 x 12 to 15 30kg

**Saturday Observation**

Saturday I train the muscle I consider it is behind and must get more attention

The problem with my program is that I cannot make use of the 48 hour recovery time that my body gives me.

I want to point out that I do every exercise slow and with low weights 4 seconds down 2 seconds up and fully extend them(no cheating).

**Edit**

Another thing I forgot to say before each training session I do 20 minutes of HIIT on the threadmill

Comment: Why do you do HIIT cardio before weight lifting? Are you not trying to increase your muscle mass? Cardio first will tire you before you start working out, which then means you can't push as hard with weights. Is cardio your priority?

Comment: I do HIIT cardio because from what I read (and I read alot about it) HIIT helps you loose fat while keep your muscle .I am not over training my cardio just doing like 7-8 sets of 1 minute each running at max speed and max inclination takes 20 minutes because 3 minutes I walk at the start to get ready for it and 3 minutes I have cooldown and 1 minute of walking between each set

Comment: My point wasn't over training or not. Simply that if you expend a lot of energy on cardio on HIIT before you start lifting, your lifting will suffer. You need to make a decision on your priority. HIIT can wait until the end if you want to maximize your muscle gain since you will have more energy to lift. If you want to prioritize the cardio part of your workout, that is fine too.

Comment: I was not doing this HIIT all the times,I was doing only the lifting part before .It is true I am very tired after the HIIT but if I do it or not I still lift the same.Tested this already,I don't know why but not doing it doesn't improve my lifting power.

Comment: This has been flagged as being primarily opinion based. I disagree, but it is borderline. If you could edit it to take out the "is it good/bad" question, and instead state "Here is where I started, here is where I am, here is where I want to be. Is this program sufficient", then the program can be weighed against those goals, rather than a vague "good/bad" schism. Also, the current weights you are using for the reps might help as well.

Comment: I will edit my question in the next few hours

Comment: After having read your post, I get the impression you are over training.  Performing 20 to 28 sets for a particular body part is counter productive, in my opinion, for building lasting muscle mass.

Comment: @rrirower so in your oppinion I should split 2 body parts per day? and train them 2 times per week or?

Comment: No, that’s not what I’m saying.  I’m not commenting on the structure of your program.  Rather, I’m saying that the total daily volume of work for individual body parts is pretty large.  Remember, more is not better, especially if you train drug free.  You should look to train harder and smarter, not, longer.

Comment: I am drug free and try to stay away from any of that crap,that is why I always try to get the most of everything.

Comment: If your weight and body fat measurements are correct you have already gained 6.7kg of muscle at half the body fat you used to be, which is already a great accomplishment.
You want to increase your current lean body mass by another 10.5kg. This is not very realistic unless you have been working out for just a few months or if you are still a teenager.

About your program: I would do a little less volume and focus on heavier weights. It is also very important that you allow your muscles enough rest between workouts, especially when you want to stay drug free.

Comment: @C.T. I am 24 years old ,but still why do you say it is not very realistic? Why can't a person that gives time and dedication get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

### **Nutrition**

Taking for granted that your nutrition is on point, when i am saying on point i mean that you know and count your daily calorie intake and your macros by at least 95% correct (you can never by 100% sure if you have eaten 500 or 505 calories per meal, or that was 40carb/40prot/20fat or 37/41/22). Also, i asume that now you are in high calorie diet. Excuse me if that short prologue sound silly if you already know those things but i want to be 100% clear that this is your ticket, if you don't know it, and also be clear for everyone else that will read it.

So, let's go to your training.

> Another thing I forgot to say before each training session I do 20
>   minutes of HIIT on the threadmill

Just stop it. It's ok to do a 5-10 minute warm up, but 20 minute HIIT before each workout? You can't expect nothing from that, either losing fat or control it. Think it in the other way, if you are doing now a 20 minute HIIT before each workout what are you going to do at summer? Or when you will be at, let me say, 95kg and 12% body fat? Your body will get used of it and then it won't be any surprise, so it won't trigger it anymore to burn the fat. Don't use strong weapons so early, unless your only goal is to lose weight (both fat and muscle) and only that.

You can do a 5-10 minute warm up before the workout and **after** your workout a 20 minute **fast walking** in treadmill with a medium incline.

Before we go to your split, i have to say that this not a split, this will just make your body sore and more sore and more. Maybe you will see results and you keep seeing when you are a beginner but not with the right way, so we come to the second of all.

---

Second of all:

### **Rest**

> The problem with my program is that I cannot make use of the 48 hour
>   recovery time that my body gives me.

The problem is that your program is so wrong organised, that's why you can't have a 48 hour recovery **for each muscle**.

Overtraining doesn't necessary mean that you will grow. Muscles grow when they rest, not when you train them. When you train the muscle you "destroy" it, giving him the time he need to recover will make him grow as it will need more "space" every time to reconstituted totally. That's the mucle building process or muscle growth or getting bigger and stronger. So, we will make an appropriate split that will let you get the time you need to rest and recover every week.

---

### **Training**

We finally come to last thing of the three, Nutrition/Rest/Training, the Training. Okay i have said it before, this is not a split, let me explain why. Could it be one of the baddest split. You are training the three big muscle groups every next day and you are training last arms and shoulders. 
Not only you can't have the time to recover but you are burning you body in totally wrong way.

After all, we got to the point. Let's choose an appropriate split that will surprise your body and let you rest - grow. It's not that usual split but it's a correct and an excellent one. That's a 7-day split. You can start with Day 1 and end to Day 7 at any range you prefer.

You are free to choose the exercises you like but they shouldn't be escersices that you are doing too long, and you have get used of them, and they should be exercises thay hit the whole muscle group at every workout. Here is a proper split/exercise program:

**Day 1 - Shoulders/Traps/Triceps**

- Push Press
- Arnold Press
- Lateral Raises
- Bent Over Lateral Raises
- High Cable Lateral Raises
- Dumbbell Shrugs
- Pressdown
- Lying Dumbbell Triceps Extension
- Overhead Dumbbell Triceps Extension

**Day 2 - Back / Abs**

- Pulldowns with open grip
- Pullups with medium grip
- Barbell Row
- Seated Cable Rows
- Deadlifts
- Hyperextensions
- Crunches
- Leg Raise on straight bench
- Plank

**Day 4 - Chest / Biceps**

- Incline Barbell Press
- Incline Dumbbell Flyes
- Dumbbell Press
- Pullover
- Preacher Curls
- Dumbbell Curls with straight back against the wall
- Concentration Dumbbell Curls

**Day 5 - Legs**

- Barbell Squats
- Front Barbell Squats
- Leg Extensions
- Lying Leg Curls
- Romanian Deadlifts
- Standing Calf Raises
- Seated Calf Raises

For Day 6 if you decide to add another workout, you can choose the excerises.

---

Considering that split what we can see is that we start the week with small muscle groups that will allow us to go as heavy as we want and let our arms grow much more (going heavy in Triceps is the point on big arms). Second day, we hit the one of the three big muscle groups, we hit it alone as we do on legs too, because chest works together when we train arms and shoulders. That's why we isolate the back at a single day, hitting lower and upper back and abs too. Third day rest, we will leave 48 hours pass before we workout arms again, we have hit them on first day and tomorrow they will work for chest too but they would have the time to recover. Also back will have it's time to recover before we need it again to workout together on leg day (yeah back collaborate with legs on some excersices). Forth and fifth day looks logical now.

For the sixth day, again, i suggest resting but it's ok if you want to isolate a muscle group and hit it twice a week, i wouldn't suggest that to be back or legs, or even big lifts for chest. It would be ok to hit arms, if you want to and need to. But not necessary.

I would suggest to run this program for 12 weeks. For reps i would suggest to run a pyramid by changing the reps every 3 weeks. A nice pyramind would be:

- **Weeks 1-3 : 12/10/8 reps per set**
- **Weeks 4-6 : 10/10/8 reps per set**
- **Weeks 7-9 : 8/8/6 reps per set**
- **Weeks 10-12 : 8/6/6 reps per set**

For Abs and Calfs go to **20-30 reps** for **4 sets**. On each day the **first** excersice go for **4 sets**, **first** will be a **low weight warm up**.

That's all.

Comment: Still I must ask would working 2 groups per day finishing all the large ones (chest+biceps,back+triceps,legs+shoulder) in 3 days and then redoing the cycle again so that in 6 days you work each group 2 times will that be an overkill?Would that not help my gains?

Comment: What i suggest for you is already written in my answer. I tried to point out mistakes, as clearly as i could, that most of the beginners do at first. Please read carefully what i write on Rest part and at the end of Training part.

Answer (score 0):

Gaining mass is about workout volume and previous comments on over training may be valid but that can depend on how you feel. Most things I have read state gains can be limited by the HIIT. Personally Looking at the program I would try cutting that down and change your target reps to 8-10 range with increasing weights. Also try to change up your workouts to make sure you are really challenging our muscles to work harder.

Comment: To build strength (and therefore muscle mass), consider keeping the exercises the same and only increasing the work-weight; _unnecessary_ exercise variation ("change up your workouts") is not _training_, unless your training goal is to ... do bunch of different stuff.

Comment: Building muscle mass and building strength are not mutually inclusive. Strength is about the output force of muscles and mass is the product of the repair that occurs for the damage caused to the muscles. There are different training regiments for each.